# HttpClient Await PostAsync not completed

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have an asmx Web Service and I am using async Task. My problem is whenever I reached on the PostAsync statement it will just end there and fire a result to the browser with an empty result. Which is not I want. I tried passing the httpclient as a parameter to my service class thinking it may solved the issue.
I tried putting ConfigureAwait(false) and it gives a result however I don't want this because I need to return the value to the user. If I use ConfigurAwait(false) it will return an empty result to the browser even if it it still not completed. Am I doing this right? Thanks

in my webmethod

```
 public class WebService1 : WebService
 {
      HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();    
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    [WebMethod]
    private async Task<String> Sample1(string a, int b)
    {
       myServiceClass _ms = new myServiceClass(Client);
       var message = await _ms.GetResponseMessageAsync(a,b);
       doc = await _ms.ReadResponseAsync(message); // It will not reach here if I don't use ConfigureAwait(false)
       return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
    }
 }
```

```
  myServiceClass.cs
  public class myServiceClass
  {
     HttpClient _client;
    
     public myServiceClass(HttpClient client)
     {
        _client = client;
     }

     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessageAsync(string a, int b)
     {
        HttpResponseMessage message;
        httpcontent = (a,encoding.UTF8,"text/xml"); //This is just a sample content
         message =  await _client.PostAsync(UrlString, httpcontent); //<= here it stops and return empty result if there is no ConfigureAwait(false).
                if (!message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException($"Cannot connect to api: {message.StatusCode} , {message.ReasonPhrase}");                   
                }
         return message; // It will not reach here if I don't use ConfigureAwait(false)
     }
  }
```

Comment: WebMethod/ASMX came around way before the async/await improvements to C#. I doubt it will play nicely with it. Have you considered adding MVC or Web API to your project, which have proper async/await support? They can both exist in the same project.

Comment: I did not use mvc web api because this is what they want me to do. If this is the case then I will just remove that async/await and back to webclient. but I am hoping if there is another way around to make this work in ASMX.

Comment: You're the person implementing the code. If someone asks you to do something but they don't understand the pitfalls of what they're asking for, then communicate that to them. Explain why they need to embrace a better paradigm.